# tput doesn't set color in the terminal

Tags: tput

I wish to colorize my terminal while using interactive shell, namely the command prompt. I managed to do this using escape sequences:

```
PS1="\e[93m prompt> \e[0m"
```

I want to use `tput` instead of escape sequences. Like that:

```
PS1="$(tput setaf 1) prompt> "
```

However, this doesn't yeld any color.

I tried other `tput` subcommands in different ways. None of them gave any effect except of `tput cols` and `tput lines` which gave appropriate output.

How should I use `tput` properly in this case?